# why does numpy.linarg.solve give different answer?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to solve a matrix equation Ax=b with numpy.linarg.solve()

```
A = np.array([[1, 1], [15,10]])
b = np.array([12,170])
sol = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
print(sol)
```

the result is

```
[10.  2.]
```

this is right answer
but, when I run the code below,

```
print(sol[0], sol[1])
```

I get

```
10.000000000000002 1.999999999999998
```

why are they different?

Comment: They are the same values, printing the array in your first line just rounds the values to make them prettier during printing

Answer (score 0):

Numpy truncates the values for print expected to be integers (i.e 1.99999999997 = 2)